# How using python to find index with logic in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my data:

```
           time           id    w
0   2018-03-01 00:00:00 39.0    1176.000000
1   2018-03-01 00:15:00 39.0    NaN
2   2018-03-01 00:30:00 39.0    NaN
3   2018-03-01 00:45:00 39.0    NaN
4   2018-03-01 01:00:00 39.0    NaN
5   2018-03-01 01:15:00 39.0    NaN
6   2018-03-01 01:30:00 39.0    NaN
7   2018-03-01 01:45:00 39.0    1033.461538
8   2018-03-01 02:00:00 39.0    1081.066667
9   2018-03-01 02:15:00 39.0    1067.909091
10  2018-03-01 02:30:00 39.0    NaN
11  2018-03-01 02:45:00 39.0    1051.866667
12  2018-03-01 03:00:00 39.0    1127.000000
13  2018-03-01 03:15:00 39.0    1047.466667
14  2018-03-01 03:30:00 39.0    1037.533333
```

I want to get index: 10

Because I need to know which time not continuous and I need to add the value.

I want to know if there is a NAN in front of and behind each 'time'. If not I need to know it index. I need to add value for it.

My data is very large. I need a faster way.

I really need your help.Many thanks.

Comment: it seems you are want to get rows by date logic... if this is the case please edit your post and explain what is the logic exactly

Comment: I have updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you correctly. If you want the index of the column `time` where the change is more than 15 minutes, you will have more index than 4, and you can do so:

```
df['time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['Delta']=(df['time'].subtract(df['time'].shift(1)))
df['Delta'] = df['Delta'].astype(str)
print df.index[df['Delta'] != '0 days 00:15:00.000000000'].tolist()
```

And the output is:

```
[4561, 4723, 5154, 5220, 5293, 5437, 5484]
```

#### Edit

Again, if I understood you right, just use this:

```
df.index[(pd.isnull(df['w'])) & (pd.notnull(df['w'].shift(1))) & (pd.notnull(df['w'].shift(-1)))].tolist()
```

Output:

```
[10]
```

Comment: @@Joe - Thanks for your answer, I have updated my article question. What should I do if I want to find a logical index?

Answer (score 1):

This should work pretty fast:

```
import numpy as np

index = np.array([4561,4723,4724,4725,4726,5154,5220,5221,5222,5223,5224,5293,5437,5484,5485,5486,5487])

continuous = np.diff(index) == 1
not_continuous = np.where(~continuous[1:] & ~continuous[:-1])[0] + 1 # check on both 'sides', +1 because you 'loose' one index in the diff operation
index[not_continuous]

array([5154, 5293, 5437])
```

It doesn't handle the first value well but this is quite ambiguous since you don't have a preceding value to check against. Up to you to add this extra check if it matters to you... Same for last value, potentially.

Comment: @@Julien - Thanks for your answer, I have updated my article question. What should I do if I want to find a logical index?